# Add array elements to associative array

Tags: php, arrays

I am unable to find a way to take the elements of an array (product IDs) and add them to a particular key of an associative array ($choices['id]) so that it creates as many instances of that array ($choices[ ]) as there are elements in $id.

I want the final version of $choices[ ] to include as many arrays as there are elements in $id[ ].

After that I want to repeat this process for part_numbers & quantity.

```
// Create $choices array with keys only
$choices = array(
    'id' => '',
    'part_number' => '',
    'quantity' => '',
);

// Insert $id array values into 'id' key of $choices[]
$id = array('181', '33', '34');
```

Comment: Why not have an array that has id, pn, and qty instead of 3 ids in one and 3 pn in another etc...?

Comment: Could you please post code for of your own best attempt, and point out what has not worked as you expected?

Comment: I am collecting three pieces of data for each selected item (ID, PN, Qty). @AbraCadaver. Thanks! Instead of three strings with corresponding data (ID: 1,2,3) (PN: 11,22,33) and (Qty:3,2,1), I wanted to organize it this way:  [1] ID:1, PN: 11, Qty:3 [2] ID:2, PN:22, Qty:2, and [3] ID:3, PN:33, Qty:1. I am open to any way to organize this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you mean something like this?

```
$choices = array();
$id = array('181', '33', '34');

foreach($id as $element)
{
    $choices[] = array(
    'id' => $element,
    'part_number' => '',
    'quantity' => '',
    );
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($choices);
echo "</pre>";
```

Output:

```
 Array (
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 181
            [part_number] => 
            [quantity] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 33
            [part_number] => 
            [quantity] => 
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 34
            [part_number] => 
            [quantity] => 
        )

)
```

Edit:

A more general solution would be as follows:

```
$choices = array();

$values = array('sku-123', 'sku-132', 'sku-1323');

foreach($values as $i => $value){
   if(array_key_exists($i, $choices))
   {
      $choices[$i]['part_number'] = $value;
   }
   else
   {
       $choices[] = array(
        'id' => '',
        'part_number' => $value,
        'quantity' => '',
    );
   }
}
```

This can be used for array creation and insertion, hence the if/else block.

Comment: Yes! Thanks Martyn Shutt. I suspected that a foreach loop was the solution, but I could not put it together correctly to make it work. Fantastic and FAST! Thanks!

Comment: @JimB814 Glad I could be of help.

Comment: I just discovered that repeating this for the next array ($part_numbers) creates three new arrays rather than using the same three arrays. Can you address this, or should I submit a new question?

Comment: @JimB814 I can address it with an edit to my question.

Comment: @JimB814 My edit should provide you with a reusable solution.

Comment: Thanks Martyn Shutt. I will have to study this to understand it. Thanks for the extra work!

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot understand this. It functions to add the data to the correct key in $choices[ ] . Yes, that's good. But when I modify the code instructions for a different array, it puts the data into the correct key in $choices[ ], but also erases the previously entered data in the other key, leaving an empty string. I want to get all the data from each of the three arrays ($id, $part_numbers, $quantities) into $choices[ ]. If I am taking too much of your time, I understand. I can resubmit my question. Let me know. Thanks again.

Comment: @JimB814 You might have been copying the line where the array is being created. This should clear things up: https://gist.github.com/martynshutt/ba4ca694ca2c783df5b5

Comment: It works and looks beautiful! Thanks for putting that out there. Coincidentally, just this morning I was reading about array_key_exists at php.net. But seeing a function in use is a far better teacher. Thanks for taking your time and helping me achieve this goal. I plan to review your solution because I do not yet grasp it the way I want to. Thank you in Wales from the US.